# getElementById().appendChild() refuses to work!

Tags: javascript, json, getelementbyid, appendchild, last.fm

Im trying to append some JSON data from the last.fm API,

I have been using alert() at several stages to verify the API is being parsed correctly and it is,

This has led me to the conclusion that getElementById().appendChild() doesn't work, below is the URL to the test page I have set up:

http://mutant-tractor.com/tabtest.html

Code here

```
 
function calculateDateAgo(secAgo) {
 var agoString, agoRange, agoScaled;
 if(secAgo >= (agoRange = 60*60*24)) 
   agoString = (agoScaled = Math.floor(secAgo/agoRange))+" "+(agoScaled>1?"days":"day") + " ago"
 else if(secAgo >= (agoRange = 60*60))
   agoString = (agoScaled = Math.floor(secAgo/agoRange))+" "+(agoScaled>1?"hours":"hour") + " ago"
 else if(secAgo >= (agoRange = 60))
   agoString = (agoScaled = Math.floor(secAgo/agoRange))+" "+(agoScaled>1?"minutes":"minute") + " ago"
 else if(secAgo >= -60)
   agoString = "blastin' out now";
 else
   agoString = "soon ;)";
 return agoString
}

function truncateName(name, l) {
return name.length > l ? name.substr(0,l-2) + "\u2026" : name
}

function lfmRecentTracks(JSONdata) {

try { 
 var eImg, eLink, eSpan, divTag, eWrapper;
 var oTracks = new Array().concat(JSONdata.recenttracks.track);
 for (var i = 0; i [lessthanhere] oTracks.length; i++) {
  //insert track link
  spanTag = document.createElement("span");
  spanTag.className = "lfmTrackInfoCell tabslider";
  eLink = document.createElement("a");
  eLink.appendChild(document.createTextNode( truncateName(oTracks[i].name, 25) ));
  //alert(truncateName(oTracks[i].name, 25));
  spanTag.appendChild(eLink);
  eLink.href = oTracks[i].url;
  //alert(oTracks[i].url);
  eLink.target = "new";
  eLink.className = "lfmTrackTitle";
  document.body.appendChild(spanTag);

  //insert artist name
  eSpan = document.createElement("span");
  eSpan.appendChild(document.createTextNode(truncateName(oTracks[i].artist["#text"], 22) ));
  //alert(truncateName(oTracks[i].artist["#text"], 22));
  eSpan.className = "lfmTrackArtist";
  document.body.appendChild(eSpan);

  //insert date
  eSpan = document.createElement("span");
  spanTag.appendChild(eSpan);
  eSpan.appendChild(document.createTextNode(   (typeof oTracks[i].date=="undefined"?"now playing":calculateDateAgo(new Date().getTime()/1000 - oTracks[i].date.uts))  )); 
  //alert((typeof oTracks[i].date=="undefined"?"now playing":calculateDateAgo(new Date().getTime()/1000 - oTracks[i].date.uts))); 
  eSpan.className = "lfmTrackDate"; 
  document.body.appendChild(eSpan);
 }  
} catch(e) {}
}
```

The only way it works is by using document.body.appendChild()

I'm calling the script in the head if that makes a difference?

The div I'm trying to attach them to are 4 different divs i.e. in the for loop each loop needs to reference a different element,

Thanks in advance!
Myles

Comment: I don't see getElementById in the code here, but I absolutely believe it works.

Comment: How do you reproduce the error on your test page?

Comment: Generating DOM elements in straight code is very error prone. You might to to look into templating engines. http://api.jquery.com/category/plugins/templates/ or http://code.google.com/closure/templates/docs/helloworld_js.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I'm calling the script in the head if that makes a difference?

You won't be able to `getElementById()` if the document body hasn't even been parsed. In other words, you need to run your code in an `window.onload` function, or place it at the very bottom of your body.

Also, remove the `try/catch` while testing, it will only hide errors.

Comment: No reason for a try catch whatsoever, even in production

Comment: @Juan - there *are* legitimate uses for it; possibly not in the code provided, but there are real uses. Let's not get dogmatic for no reason.

Comment: @Juan: Sizzle makes nice use of `try/catch` in hopes of successfully using `querySelectorAll`. If a selector string was used that utilizes one of Sizzle's features that is a non-valid selector, `querySelectorAll` throws an error, and Sizzle redirects to its own engine.

Comment: I meant, I don't see a reason for the code in question, I don't mean never at all. I suppose my comment was not clear.

Comment: Ahh okay that makes sense, I'll try putting it at the end of the body, if that works ill try call it externally with window.onload.

Comment: Update: I have added the window.onLoad function as below: function init() {[ALL CODE HERE]} window.onLoad = init; but it has broken the whole script, i also removed the try/catch and am trying to debug with firebug, but no luck :(

Comment: Well, if you have other scripts that rely on `window.onload`, then that would certainly cause it; this is one of the many reasons people use libraries like jQuery which have code that prevents such a problem. If you don't want to go with a library, though, then you might try the technique as demonstrated here: http://haacked.com/archive/2006/04/06/StopTheWindow.OnloadMadness.aspx

Comment: @ken - I would go with a library but I have only very limited straight Java experience, so I thought my best option was to go with straight JavaScript too, What would it take to convert this from plain old JS to JQuery?

Comment: Tough call. I think it's bad to jump right into a library when you don't understand the underlying language much, but OTOH, libraries were created to smooth-over common language problems and provide a more usable API. On to your question: it would take about 5m to convert this to jQuery (if done by someone experienced in jQuery). I would recommend you ask a new question here on SO so that you can see the benefits.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that the element you're trying to get has been loaded into the DOM? You said that your script runs in the head tag (which loads before the rest of the body loads). It's possible that your script is being run before the DOM element you're searching for exists, and therefore it can't find it and therefore it can't add to it.

Answer (score 0):

There's no guarantee that the HTML will have finished parsing by the time the JavaScript executes.  There are several ways of doing what you want, with different performance characteristics.

You can put your code in a function and assign it as the load event handler for the window object.  This has the downside of waiting until all resources for the page have finished loading, not just the HTML.  This often slows down page load times, as you need to wait for things like slow ad servers etc.

You can put your code in a function and call it from bottom of the document.

You can use a JavaScript library such as jQuery to execute your JavaScript when the DOM has finished loading.  There isn't a simple way of doing this that works cross-browser, so it's simplest not to reinvent the wheel and just to use what is already a mature solution.